# How to check programmatically if Magento getSelectionsCollection don't have any product

Tags: magento, bundle

what is this output of `$selectionCollection` given if no selection product is found in this code for magento bundle product list

```
$bundled_product_custom = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$bundled_product_custom->load($bundleParentProductId);
$selectionCollection = $bundled_product_custom->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
          $bundled_product_custom->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled_product_custom), $bundled_product_custom
         );
```

Actually I need to check if this bundle product has selection products or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should avoid instantiating an object with the `new` operator. I suggest you use the Magento's factory method as shown below:

```
$bundled_product_custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

This way if a third party extension overrides the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class then the factory method instantiates the right object according to the override rules.

To answer your question, try to count the elements in the collection this way:

```
$selectionCollection->count();
// or
count($selectionCollection);
```